# Starting supervisor with Docker and seeing its logs in docker logs, but not finding the service with service supervisor status in the container

Tags: docker, supervisord

I want to run supervisor to have multiple processes in the same container, as I can't use docker-compose in our current hosting environment. Things seems to work when I look in the docker logs, but I can't see the supervisor service inside the linux system when I've attached my terminal to the container.

When I check the logs for the container I get:

```
Starting supervisord.... (entrypoint.sh)
2021-12-22 08:38:50,871 CRIT Supervisor is running as root.  Privileges were not dropped because no user is specified in the config file.  If you intend to run as root, you can set user=root in the config file to avoid this message.
2021-12-22 08:38:50,877 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2021-12-22 08:38:50,877 CRIT Server 'inet_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2021-12-22 08:38:50,878 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
```

However, if I attach my shell to the container and run "service supervisor status" I get:

> supervisord is  not running.

And I don't get why the system don't seem to recognise that the service is running. Can anyone help me figuring this out, because if I can't access the service from the terminal I can't really manage it in any way.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y pgbouncer
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y supervisor

# install nginx
ENV NGINX_VERSION 1.15.12-1~stretch
ENV NJS_VERSION   1.15.12.0.3.1-1~stretch
RUN set -x \
    && \
    NGINX_GPGKEY=573BFD6B3D8FBC641079A6ABABF5BD827BD9BF62; \
    found=''; \
    for server in \
        hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 \
        hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 \
        pgp.mit.edu \
    ; do \
        echo "Fetching GPG key $NGINX_GPGKEY from $server"; \
        apt-key adv --keyserver "$server" --keyserver-options timeout=10 --recv-keys "$NGINX_GPGKEY" && found=yes && break; \
    done; \
    test -z "$found" && echo >&2 "error: failed to fetch GPG key $NGINX_GPGKEY" && exit 1; \
    apt-get remove --purge --auto-remove -y gnupg1 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && dpkgArch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)" \
    && nginxPackages=" \
        nginx=${NGINX_VERSION} \
        nginx-module-xslt=${NGINX_VERSION} \
        nginx-module-geoip=${NGINX_VERSION} \
        nginx-module-image-filter=${NGINX_VERSION} \
        nginx-module-njs=${NJS_VERSION} \
    " \
    && echo "deb https://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ stretch nginx" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y \
                        $nginxPackages \
                        gettext-base \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list


# install app
RUN mkdir /var/app && chown www-data:www-data /var/app
WORKDIR /var/app
COPY ./requirements.txt /var/app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /var/app/

COPY ./conf/nginx/staging.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./conf/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.ini /etc/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.ini
COPY ./supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

VOLUME /var/logs

# Expose ports (Added from previous dockerfile)
EXPOSE 80 2222 

# Added for setting right permissions to entrypoint script 
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "./entrypoint.sh"]
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/var/app/bin/staging/django-q.sh"]

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

This is my entrypoint.sh - I first set-up some settings for pg-bouncer, and then start supervisor

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

# SET UP PG BOUNCER
PG_CONFIG_DIR=/etc/pgbouncer

invoke_main(){
    check_variables
    create_config
}

check_variables(){
    ...
}

error(){
  ...
}

create_databases_config(){
 ...
}

create_config(){
 ... 
}

[databases]
$(create_databases_config)

[pgbouncer]
...

invoke_main

# INVOKE SUPERVISORD
echo " Starting supervisord.... (entrypoint.sh)"
exec supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
#exec supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
```

This is my supervisord.conf

```
[supervisord]
logfile=/var/logs/supervisord.log   ; main log file; default $CWD/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes=50MB               ; max main logfile bytes b4 rotation; default 50MB
logfile_backups=10                  ; # of main logfile backups; 0 means none, default 10
loglevel=info                       ; log level; default info; others: debug,warn,trace
pidfile=/var/logs/supervisord.pid
nodaemon=true                       ; Run interactivelly instead of deamonizing
# user=www-data

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[inet_http_server]
port = 127.0.0.1:9001

[supervisorctl]
serverurl = http://127.0.0.1:9001
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are starting `supervisord` manually. `service` command won't report its status correctly.